# copy qt scene to clipboard as a PowerPoint object

Tags: qt, powerpoint

I was wondering if anyone knew the first thing about copying a qt scene to the clipboard and then being able to paste it into word as a grouped object. All I have in my scene are graphics text items, ellipses, and lines. It seems like something that could be made into shapes and lines and text that could be pasted into powerPoint as a group. I don't know where to start! Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would attack this in two ways:

From the system perspective and from the office sdk perspective.

From the system perspective you are talking about the clipboard, mime types, and exactly what is stored in the clipboard, exactly.

From the office sdk perspective, you are talking about how it stores the pre-rendered elements.

Just from a quick look around, I found this info in the MS Office SDK:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/gg278315

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/cc850847

and this on Clipboard managers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_manager

and this for the Qt connection to the clipboard:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html#details

Now... from that start, I wrote this little bit of code:

I added a `QPushButton` and a `QTextEdit` to a MainWindow UI Form.  Then I went to the slot of the Push Button and put the following:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->textEdit->clear();
    QClipboard *c = QApplication::clipboard();
    foreach(QString format, c->mimeData()->formats())
    {
        ui->textEdit->append(format);
        ui->textEdit->append(c->mimeData()->data(format));
    }
    ui->textEdit->append("done");
}
```

I copied an oval and a rectangle from PowerPoint in Office 2010,

[image]

and then used the push button in my program.  This is the output it gave me:

```
application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="Preferred DropEffect"

application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="InShellDragLoop"

application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="PowerPoint 12.0 Internal Shapes"
ÀN
application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="Object Descriptor"
j
application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="Art::GVML ClipFormat"
PK
application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="PNG"
PNG


application/x-qt-image

application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="JFIF"
ÿØÿà
application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="GIF"
GIF89aã
application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="PowerPoint 12.0 Internal Theme"
Hý©
application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="PowerPoint 12.0 Internal Color Scheme"
Pý©
done
```

So it should be do-able, but you would need to figure out what is some of the stuff they are encoding in between the readable clear text.

Hope that helps.

PS You may have better luck trying to save the Qt elements as an SVG object or some other image on the clipboard.

Comment: This is great! I've searched forever and have not been able to find anything about what is being encoded. I might take your suggestion for a different object. I'm thinking I want to put a metafile on the clipboard. Is this a possibility?

Comment: The `QClipboard` class should enable you to do a lot of different things.  Read the docs and try it out.  See what you can do with it.  Good luck.